# Rendering - Material problem

Tags: rendering, materials, uv

I'm new in Blender, totally noob :) but I try to learn.

I make some kitchen sinks in Inventor and inport them as STL to blender, and when I apply material (brushed aluminum) on circle sink I have a "glitch", but when I apply same material to square sink there is no "glitch".
I know that problem is with UV mapping, but I can not find solution to fix it. I try several options:

1. Unwrap (but then my material become blurred)
2. I try dissolve faces but then my model is deformed
3. Manually move faces in UV mapping, they are so tiny and overlapped with other faces.

Can some one please help me because I can not render quality image :(

[image: Rendered image]
[image: UV Mapping]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (make sure that the images are packed)? Maybe you need to unwrap again, or use another method like the Object output of the Texture Coordinate?

Comment: Do not use _Dissolve Faces_, but _Limited Dissolve_. In the tool options on the bottom left then adjust the angle up to which edges should be dissolved... usually the default is 5° which can be too high to keep the shape, try 1°. Just in general, the mesh is really messy as it comes in the STL and definitely needs cleaning up. After the _Limited Dissolve_ the UV map might probably be messed up and needs to be unwrapped again.